# What's the most recommended cross platform C++ library?

Tags: c++

Is there something like jQuery that works the same in all browsers in the c/c++ world that will work consistently in all platforms?

Comment: There are hundreds of cross platform C++ libraries.  Like the STL.  What are you asking?  What are you looking to do with this cross platform library, so we can suggest it for you?

Comment: With a core library and plugins,it should do everything in the same manner.

Comment: @mysql_go: Do you mean a GUI library?  A web library?  Or just any old library that does anything, and happens to support plugins?  Add this to your question.

Comment: It should be a family of libraries,that can deal with all stuff consistently.

Comment: @mysql_go: C++ is used in way too many different fields to have a single family of libraries that does everything.

Comment: @mysql_go: Add your answers to your question, and say what you're looking to solve.  One thing that is highly smiled upon on stack overflow is useful questions that people can search for to get an answer to a problem they have.  Vague questions with no possible concrete answer tend to be frowned upon.

Comment: If it was easily searched for, he wouldn't have asked. He's asking for the most solid general-purpose cross-platform library to get started in. It is a clear and common type of question. If you don't have an answer, please leave it to those who do and don't close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is one of the most used one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about for GUI elements?  [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) is very popular.

Comment: It has lots of other libraries too, like for sockets and some ADTs

Answer (score 2):

[Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) is intended to act as a facade for the system's native libc.